# Code overwrites variables although it should not

Tags: c++, c++11, conditional-statements, c++14, do-while

the following code snippet is a part of a TicTacToe game.
The problem I have is, that whenever I run the code and get to the point where I enter the row and column the code works just fine except for one thing. When I enter row 1 column 1 the code will display the first X properly but the moment I enter a second row 1 column 1 it switches the X in the grid with an O although it should not. I thought the condition in the do while loop was enough to not let the grid be overwritten when entering a row/column combination a second time. But it seems it does not.

```
char grid[3][3] = { 
    {' ', ' ', ' '},
    {' ', ' ', ' '},
    {' ', ' ', ' '}
    };

do {
    int row, column;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
        do {
            ...
            ...
            std::cout << "* Enter row   : ";
            std::cin >> row;
            std::cout << "* Enter column: ";
            std::cin >> column;

        } while ((row < 1 || row > 3) && (column < 1 || column > 3) && (grid[row-1][column-1] != ' '));

        if (i % 2 == 0)
            grid[row-1][column-1] = 'O';
        else
            grid[row-1][column-1] = 'X';
    }   // For loop close
} while (true);
```

Hope you guys can help me out there. Have a nice evening. Cheers.

Comment: you loop while all the conditions are true (`&&`) but if I understand correctly already one condition true would be an invalid move (ie use `||` instead)

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger to see exactly what it's doing? If not, why not?

Answer (score -1):

Is it what you are looking for?

```
char grid[3][3] = { 
    {' ', ' ', ' '},
    {' ', ' ', ' '},
    {' ', ' ', ' '}
    };

int i = 0;

do {
    int row, column;
        do {
            ...
            ...
            std::cout << "* Enter row   : ";
            std::cin >> row;
            std::cout << "* Enter column: ";
            std::cin >> column;

        } while (row < 1 || row > 3 || column < 1 || column > 3 || (grid[row-1][column-1] != ' ')); //Check if input is valid.

        if (i % 2 == 0)
            grid[row-1][column-1] = 'O';
        else
            grid[row-1][column-1] = 'X';

        i++; //Increment i only if input is valid.
} while (9 > i); //Exit the loop when all 9 valid inputs are entered.
```

I removed the for loop, so that it will take care of wrong inputs.

Comment: Thanks a lot that fixed it for me :)

Comment: @xcuse.h4x My code was entering to infinite loop. I have made a small change (added "while (9 > i)"). Take this change to your project.